# How to update/delete value in object using redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, state, action, reducers

I am working on an app where a user fills out a form (using redux-forms) and adds a name and a weight to the state. The state looks as follows:

```
[
 {
  name: squat,
  weight: 100,
  id: 1
 }
]
```

I am trying to figure out how to let the user update the weight value using redux-forms. Right now, I keep getting the same state returned after the update form is filled out. I can see that the form records the new value, but when my action is executed I get the old value.
Here is my action:

```
export const updateMovement = (id, newFormValues) => async dispatch => {
    const response = await movements.patch(`/movements/${id}`, newFormValues);
    const updateId = response.data.id;
    dispatch({ type: constants.UPDATE_MOVEMENT, payload: { data: response.data, id: updateId } });
};
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = [];

const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_MOVEMENT: 
            return [
                ...state, action.payload
            ];
        case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
             return [ ...state.map(item => item.id === action.payload.id ? {...item, movementWeight: action.payload.data.movementWeight} : item)];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
    const clonedMovement = state;
    const movementIndexToUpdate = clonedMovement.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
    );
    const updatedMovement = {
      ...clonedMovement[movementIndexToUpdate],
      movementWeight: action.payload.data.movementWeight,
    };
    const updatedMovements = [...clonedMovement];
    updatedMovements[movementIndexToUpdate] = updatedMovement;
    return [...updatedMovements];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I still get my original state returned. Maybe the issue is in another part of my code then.

Comment: maybe what you can try is make the initial state as `const initialState = { movements :[] };` as its always better to keep the initial state as an object.